# Use serializer within ASP.NET Core MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET Core MVC serializes responses returned from my `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase` controller methods.

So the following will serialize a `MyDTO` object to JSON:

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpGet]
public MyDTO test() 
{
    return new MyDTO();
}
```

However, I want to use the exact same serializer within the method itself. Is that possible? Something like

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpGet]
public MyDTO test() 
{
    var result = new MyDTO();
    string serialized = this.<SOMETHING GOES HERE>(result);
    Console.WriteLine($"I'm about to return {serialized}");
    return result;
}
```

It's important that it's the same serializer, including any options set in the stack.

Comment: Why is it important to use the same serializer? Any serializer should serialize the same object to the exact same json, unless options are specified or need to be specified. If you need some specific behavior (like changing case) you can just implement your own serializer to do this or use newtonsoft with options.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think that's possible because it's hidden away within `IActionResultExecutor<JsonResult>`. Default will be the `SystemTextJsonResultExecutor` but could be overwritten on startup when using e.g. `.AddNewtonsoftJson(...)`...

You could set the Json Format Options explicitly in `startup.cs` and then just use the same options wherever else you need to serialize. That way all serializations will be done exactly the same way.

---

e.g. If you are using `JsonSerializer`:

```cs
public static class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static JsonOptions ConfigureJsonOptions(this JsonOptions options)
    {
        // your configuration
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString;
        return options;
    }
}
```

`startup.cs`

```cs
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.ConfigureJsonOptions());
```

`Conroller.cs`

```cs
string serialized =JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyDTO(), options: new JsonOptions().ConfigureJsonOptions().JsonSerializerOptions);
```